# To break nested loop

Tags: c++, loops, nested, break

I want to break the inner loop and increase the value of `x` if I find something at `Matrix[x][y]` but if I break in the `y for loop` it will just increase the value at `y loop` and not in the `x loop`.

```
int matrix[5][5]; //let's assume there are values inside
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     for(int j = 0; j<5;j++)
      {
        int radius = 1;
        for(int x = radius - 1; x <= radius + i; x ++)
         {
          for(int y = radius -1; y <= radius +j; y++)
            {
               if((x+i) >= 0 && (y+j)>=0)
                 {
      //for example I find the number 45 in the matrix, then the search radius should be increased by 1 and start it over again.
                  if(matrix[x][y] == 45)
                     {
                       radius++;
                       break; // but if i break here the x value wont be changed
                      }

                  }
             }
          }
      }
```

Comment: use `goto` statement

Comment: do you want `continue`?

Comment: You could use a variable for setting x and then increase it by 1 when found.

Comment: @Newuser1234567 Why did you decide that x will not be incremeneted after this statement break; // but if i break here the x value wont be changed?

Comment: You can change the value of `x` before the `break`.

Comment: Yeah i want to continue the search (like a picture pixel search in openCv )and increase the radius where i stopped it @king_nak

Comment: I would use a `goto` here. There is really no other way of breaking _partially_ out of a nested loop without adding checking code to the level you want to break to. (Boolean flags, numerical checks, etc.)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I wrote a program with 10 x 10 matrix and sum the neighours and how x and y goes and somehow the x didnt changed only the y value

Comment: Can you refactor the code? Might be easier to do if you could stick a `return` somewhere.

Comment: What happens to the value of 'j' and 'i'?  If you increment the radius, it will break the 'y' loop, and then test for 'x' when i=0 will cause that loop to end.  If 'j' is incremented, you know that's your problem.

Comment: also named loop idiom: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Loop

Answer (score 0):

Of non-local exit mechanisms C++ provides throwing:

```
try {
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
            std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
            if(y == 1 && x == 3) throw true;
        }
    }
}
catch(bool) {}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Additionally you can modify the outer loop's variable so the final condition holds:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
        if(y == 1 && x == 3) {
            x = 10;
            break;
        }
    }
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

(Or, if you don't want to modify the variable itself, say, it's not local to the loop and you'll need its value afterwards, add one more flag to the loop condtion:

```
bool continueOuter{true};
for(int x = 0; continueOuter && x < 10; ++x) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
        if(y == 1 && x == 3) {
            continueOuter = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

)

Comment: use of exceptions would be inappropriate for this case. Needing to increase the radius of the search is not an "exceptional circumstance". It's an expected part of the algorithm.

Comment: And where exactly do I use exceptions?

Comment: try/catch/throw involve exceptions whether or not you derive the actual exception's type from std::exception. `throw int(1)` throws an exception of type `int`.

Comment: Can you kindly clarify: by "throws an exception" do you mean it is actually an exception from something, or is it a colloquial term for a non-local exit?

Comment: see [expr.throw] in the c++ standard draft: "Evaluating a throw-expression with an operand throws an exception (18.1); the type of the exception object
is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand and adjusting the
type from “array of T” or function type T to “pointer to T”"
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf